# Jquery element.click(function(){})

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set my website's side menus fixed when you scroll the windows more than a specific number. The menus are working fine and they get fixed after scroll. This is OK but the problem is after scroll they should collapse and when you click on them they should extend but this doesn't happen! I mean it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't! I am using `addClass()` to add the fixed class to the menus!

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > (rightHeight + $('.header-wrapper').height() + $('.top-wrapper').height() + $('.back-picture').height()) + 300) {
    $('.login-fixed').fadeIn(100);
    $('.col-content').css('margin-right', '15%');
    $('.right-side').addClass('fixed');
    $('.right-side').children('.side-widget').addClass('side-widget-fixed');
    $('.right-side').children('.side-widget').click(function() {
      if ($('.right-side').children().hasClass('open')) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
          $(this).toggleClass('open');
        } else {
          $('.right-side').children().removeClass('open');
          $(this).toggleClass('open');
        }

      } else {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
      }
    });

  } else {
    $('.col-content').css('margin-right', 0);
    $('.right-side').removeClass('fixed');
    $('.right-side').children('.side-widget').removeClass('side-widget-fixed');
    $('.login-fixed').fadeOut(100);
  }

});
```

I am also trying to handle the click and it means when another menu is extended when you click on a menu the other one collapses and this one opens! I know that maybe my question is a little confusing but I am confused too.
Just for more info I should say when I edit the code it works but after refreshing 10 times or scrolling 20 times it corrupts!

Comment: Include your HTML and CSS too, please. And a live example wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: @zer00ne I want but i don't think it will help! because it's not english and also it doesn't work!

Comment: How can we help if we don't know where everything is? You may have to post simpler code, because as it is right now, every element would be guess work and any solution would be generalizations or inaccurate due to assumptions of what is there and what is not.

Comment: @zer00ne This is the whole of it! Although html has some elements but only important thing is this! i checked now again and i found out that when i scroll at the exact number i've set for script the menus don't work but when i scroll top and down more it works! but i don't know how to fix this that it will work in all distances

Comment: Well I can't help, I don't have the time to recreate a layout I've never seen. Testing would be impossible, and I couldn't trust what you test. No offense meant, but there are many things left to your perception which may not coincide with mine or vice versa. Good luck.